# not recognised excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have been trying to read some excel files using pandas but when I use the for loop to go through all the files I get an error [image]

I have checked if the files name are stored in week and they are, actually if I do try to read individually I can read the files, but as soon as I use the for I get this error

```
import pandas as pd
import os

week = [file for file in os.listdir("./data_excel")]

week_concatenated = pd.DataFrame()


for file in week:
    df = pd.read_excel('data_excel/'+file, 'DIGITAL_TASKS')
    week_concatenated = pd.concat([week_concatenated, df])
```

Comment: Does the code also takes in consideration the file format? Example .csv .xls etc?

Comment: Did you try to read all the files without the loop, or only the first one?

Comment: yes, I tried one by one and concatenated them all, but when I used the loop, error!

Comment: instead of `week = [file for file in os.listdir("./data_excel")]` you can do `week = os.listdir("./data_excel")`

Comment: first check what you have on list `week` - you may have files whixh are not excel files and you may need to filter them ie. `if file.endswith( ('xls', 'csv') ):`

Comment: before `read_excel` you could use `print( 'data_excel/'+file )` to see which path makes problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there was actually a file inside the folder that the system created and I didnt see it before, thats why when the loop was started was reading that file and throwing that error as this file was not xlsx.